# Ubuntu on Windows 8 - Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu

Simple question here - I would like to do something development work in Ruby, which seems to work way better on Ubuntu.  I'm currently running windows 8.  Is there any reason I shouldn't install Unbuntu on a virtual machine? I've looked at creating a dual boot, but it seems like an absolute nightmare...

Thanks - KC

Comment: This question is better off on [superuser](http://superuser.com) then on Stackoverflow since it's not related to programming and I'm very sure this question is already answered there.

Comment: Only if you need performance, I think.

Comment: I do somewhat the oposite: I run Windows as a VM inside a Linux host, and I don't have any problems. I supose the oposite can work just as well. However, you must take into consideration the resources you'll need: both the host and the guest OS will have performance penalties if you don't have enough RAM, for example. Besides that, I concur with @morten.c's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use a VM for multiple reasons. For one it is far easier and much less risky, plus you are still running your Host while you have your Linux development environment open. Also, you can create clones and backups far easier.

You also have far more options in terms of setting up Virtual HDD's and network shares.

Dual booting used to be the way to go if you needed both environments, using a pendrive was also an option, but once you go to a Virtual Env you will likely stay on it.

Pat